# How to configure Eclipse / STS autocomplete to suggest constructor argument names for new statements?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

My Eclipse/STS used to autocomplete a `new` statement with argument names from the original class constructor. For example, let's suppose I have a Sale class like this:

```
public class Sale {

    private Integer month;
    private Integer year;
    private String seller;
    private Integer items;
    private Double total;

    public Sale(Integer month, Integer year, String seller, Integer items, Double total) {
    ...
```

Then if I start writing a `new` statement, the autocomplete used to suggest me a constructor call using argument names:

```
Sale sale = new Sale(month, year, seller, items, total);
```

However, recently, the autocomplete is suggesting `null`, like this:

```
Sale sale = new Sale(null, null, null, null, null);
```

How to configure Eclipse / STS autocomplete to suggest constructor argument names for new statements?

Answer (score 2):

There are two strategies that can be used by the editor to propose arguments for method or constructor calls:

- best guessed arguments (this tries to find the best matching name in your scope that fits the type - but if there is no reference around in the scope where your new statement is, it inserts `null` since the editor can't find a anything that is matching)
- parameter names (this inserts the names of the parameters, independent of what is available in the scope of the new statement, sounds like this is what you are looking for)

You can switch between both options in `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist` and look for the choice below `Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments`.